# Format DisplayTag column

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I want if the value is `1.50` ,it should display `1.50` but it displays `1.5`. It truncates `0`

I tried below code but no luck

```
<display:column title="MTD" sortable="true" property="mtd"  format="{0,number,#.##}"></display:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at example here: http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-format.jsp
This format can help you: `format="{0,number,0,000.00} $"`